# Установка eclipse на windows 12

Tags: windows, eclipse

При запуске установщика eclipse-inst-win64 скачанного с
https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/installer
открывается браузер с страницей официального сайта eclipse, в которой указано:

> Unfortunately the Java version needed to run Eclipse Installer
> couldn't be found on your system. You need the following version or a
> higher version:

При запуске установщика eclipse-inst-jre-win64 скачанного с
https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/oomph/epp/2023-03/R/eclipse-inst-jre-win64.exe
вообще ничего не происходит. Пробовал запустить от имени администратора, 0 реакции.
JDK последней версии установлен. Прошу помощи в решении проблемы.

Comment: Какая версия указана в сообщении, которое вы процитировали не до конца, и какая версия у вас установлена?

Comment: Java 11.0.0 (64Bit)
У меня установлен: 
Java SE Development Kit 20.0.1 (64 bit)
Java SE Development Kit 17.0.7 (64 bit)
Java SE Development Kit 8 Update 361 (64 bit)
Java 8 Update 371 (64 bit)

Comment: Java 11.0.0 (64Bit) требуется

Comment: После установки Java 11.0.0 (64Bit) появилось окошко Error opening registry key 'Software\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment' В интернете есть решение с удалением файлов java.exe, javaw.exe и javaws.exe. Удаление и переустановка данных файлов к изменениям не привела.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте  обновить Java и JDK.

Вот ссылки на официальные сайты для загрузки: [скачать Java](https://www.java.com/ru/), [скачать JDK](https://www.oracle.com/cis/java/technologies/downloads/).

У меня стоит Java 8 Update 361 и JDK 20, и установщик Eclipse ведет себя нормально.

Comment: [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)